# WPF: Can I modify a TextBlock that is in a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf

So I have a custom ControlTemplate that is used in several various sections throughout the same window to display a count.

However, this count is not relevant for one of the sections and I want to remove it, which would require removing a single textblock from this template.

The call when making the window is along the lines of:

```
<ContentControl>
    <filters:__________ DataContext="______" Template="{StaticResource FilterTemplate}" />
</ContentControl>
```

Where FilterTemplate is the template that I would like to override.

The filter is quite long, so having to recopy the entire filter for such a small change would not be ideal.

Comment: Can you bind the visibility of your filter to some property of the host so you can hide it for a given criteria?

Comment: Ideally, it'd be when it has the specific section header. Is this possible to do this in wpf? I'm still new to it and don't know exactly what I'm doing

Comment: Sounds like a trigger that sets the TextBlock's Visibility to Collapsed.